how to improve DB performance by removing the query on cabs or booking table for cab management system
I have a cab management system with main entities
public class Cab {
    private int cabID;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private String model;
    private int driverID;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}

public class Booking {
    private int bookingID;
    private int userID;
    private int cabID;
    private Date date;
    private String pickupLocation;
    private String dropOffLocation;
    private String status;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}

cab and booking have one to many unidirectional relationship
I have a method to check for available cabs
approach 1 : load all bookings , filter by date and list all available cabs
private boolean isCabAvailable(Cab cab, Date date) {
        // Get all bookings for the given cab
        List<Booking> bookings = getBookingsForCab(cab);

        // Check if any of the bookings overlap with the given date
        for (Booking booking : bookings) {
            if (booking.getDate().equals(date)) {
                return false; // Cab is not available on the given date
            }
        }

        return true; // Cab is available on the given date
    }

cons
loading all bookings from a huge booking booking table
it will not consider the cabs which have never been booked yet
aproach 2 : load all cab , load all booking for cab , filter by date availability
List<Booking> bookings = getBookingsForCab(cab);

        // Check if any of the bookings overlap with the given date range
        for (Booking booking : bookings) {
            // Check if the booking overlaps with the given date range
            if (bookingOverlap(booking, startDate, endDate)) {
                return false; // Cab is not available for the entire date range
            }
        }

cons

loading 2 table , possibly a huge booking table

I am looking for suggestions to design my entity relationship better to load smaller data from the tables

Let the database do the query work. The database engine ishighly optimized for that.

Your cabs rent for the entire day?

How many million cabs do you have? And could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statements, the DLL for all tables and indexes involved and all in plain text?

Might be down-voted for a lack of relevant detail, unanswered questions in the Comments, and a lack of clarity in your Question.

By the way, never use either of the terribly flawed Date classes. They were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.

Could you pass the date to getBookingsForCab method ? getBookingsForCab(cab, date). And your postgresql query could filter on booking on this date to return a minimal resultset. With an index on date field it should be instantaneous

If you can't share your SQL statements, the DLL for all tables and indexes involved we can't help you more
